# How do I manage a users facebook "managed pages"?

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am currently working on a project where we want to post to a users facebook wall or the wall of one of a users managed pages.

See this page:  https://socialiteproviders.github.io/

Note that facebook is not listed!  Weird being it is one of the top social networks, why is it left to be a custom, override provider?

```
    return Socialite::with('facebook')->scopes(['publish_actions', 'manage_pages', 'pages_show_list'])->redirect();
```

and then

```
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```

Where can I find documentation on socialite in regards to facebook?  Specifically how do you get the information on managed pages for the user who just logged in.

We do have app permission from facebook.  When you link your account, on the facebook page it pops up asking to give permission to the app to manage pages.

When I dd() the results of ->user()

I get

```
token, refreshToken, expiresIn, id, nickname, name, email, avatar, user -> [name, email, gender, verified, link, id], avatar_original, profileUrl.
```

If I understand correctly, there should be a way to get a "data" attribute that contains information on managed pages.

see this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#multiple-pages

Am I going to have to work directly with the Facebook API, or is there a way to get this information out of socialite?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I was asking additionally about a facebook provider, and whether it was hard coded into socialite.  I have since posting this foind in vendor/laravel/socialite/SocialliteServiceProvider.php is actually wired up for facebook.  I still however, cannot figure out how to manage a facebook users "managed pages"

Answer (score 4):

You are close, in my opinion.

As you can see in the [Facebook API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-manage_pages), to give your application the ability to publish in a page that the user manages, you need to ask for `manage_pages` y `publish_pages` permissions.

On the other hand, by default Socialite will ask Facebook for the most common fields (like `id`, `email`, `name`, etc) but to get extra -driver specific- fields you need to specify them too. So this should do it:

```php
return Socialite::
            with('facebook')
            ->scopes(['manage_pages', 'publish_pages', 'the_rest_of_your_scopes'])
            ->redirect();
```

And to retrieve the user:

```php
$social_user = Socialite::
                    driver('facebook')
                    ->fields(['accounts', 'some_other_extra_fields'])
                    ->user();
```

Disclaimer: I haven't test it yet, but this should include an `accounts` key in the user object that will have an array of the user page(s), his/her role(s), page info and the token to perform actions in the page (yes, like publish).

I hope this can serve you as a guide at least. Good luck.

Comment: thank's for answering...
yeah but what i need, is to manage pages and page reviews, like someone is posted a review on my page then i will see review on my site and should be able to reply his/her review from my site.

Comment: I see.. but that's not what you wrote in your question

Comment: yes you are right. but i need to update question. if you have idea please share it or some kind of link. that would great

Comment: Socialite is helpful to log users with third party systems like Facebook/Instagram/GitHub etc. What you need is more specific imo, so try to use the Facebook PHP library or interact directly with the Facebook Graph API.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the following Official Laravel Socialite Pacakge 
(Use this Package )

> https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Facebook providers are there already.

1. Get the access token from Facebook
2. Save it to database
3. Use the graph API of facebook to access page details.
4. Send the saved access token with api requests

Alternatively you can use this package too.

> https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk